# Agora Unity demo scene webcam not detected

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

I just download Agora Unity SDK 2.9.2.2, my Unity is 2019.4.5f1. I am following the readme to run the SceneHome in Demo folder. I have a problem that I must switch to other application and back to Unity then I can see my webcam image in the Unity Game window. I build it to Window .exe and run, but I totally can't see the webcam image. My webcam is Logitech and has no problem. Could anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Hi Hong, first of all, the latest SDK version is 3.0.1.72.  Will you first update to that and retest  please?  Secondly, can you clarify what you meant by switch to other app and back to Unity? Is the other app using the webcam at the same time? Also, when you built your app, did you set the option to allow it run in background?

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing this exact same issue only on Mac. After looking into it further I saw that the OnJoinChannelSuccess callback was not firing.

After a lot of trial and error, I discovered that the appId I was using from the site had certificates enabled. I generated a new appId with certificates disabled and suddenly the Demo worked for me.

Try generating a new project ensuring that the **Authentication Method** is set to **APP_ID**

[Screenshot of Authentication Method selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQklO.png)